# Finding posts under a category name keyword with pg_search on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, pg-search

I'm using gem [`pg_search`](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) and doing multi-search for **Website** and **Post** tables. I am able to search by records title, but I also want to be able to search records based on categories they belong to.

So, for example, when I type "typographic" (category name) to search input, all Website and Post records under that category should be listed, as well as all records that have "Typographic" in the title.

I think it can be done with association but I could not make it work ‍♂️

---

*_header.html.erb*

```
<%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], placeholder: "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

---

*search_controller.rb*

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pg_search_result = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:query])
  end
end
```

---

*models/post.rb*

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch
  multisearchable :against => :title,
    using: {tsearch: {disctionary: "english"}},
    associated_against: {category: :title},
    ignoring: :accents
```

---

*models/website.rb*

```
class Website < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch
  multisearchable :against => [:title, :website_url],
    using: {tsearch: {disctionary: "english"}},
    associated_against: {website_category: :title},
    ignoring: :accents
```

Comment: Why the `Website` model in question?

Comment: will this help: https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#pg_search_scope?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I just udpated the question. I basically do multip search for Post and Website tables

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I tried that associated_against: { categories: :title } from the link, but it doesnt return records for that :/

Comment: @Designer can you try to rebuild the indexes again and search them

Comment: @rohit yes I tried that with rake. rake pg_search:multisearch:rebuild[Post] and rake pg_search:multisearch:rebuild[Website]